# FiveM CFX Server GTA FiveM weird rendering bugs

Tags: fivem

I just opened my server to beta and some people reported, that there are some parts of the map that doesn't get rendered correctly. I updated the game build and the server artifacts + disabled all mods and MLOs, but i still have the problem that not everything gets rendered like it should be. F.E this part of the map. I even disabled all ressources but i still have this issue...

[image]

I don't know whats causing the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/Bob74/bob74_ipl

This resource will fix texture issues on your fiveM Server!